# Legoings quality concerns

Tags: clone-brands

Can anyone tell me about the quality of Legoings? I'm considering a purchase from China. I can't seem to find any reviews on this clone brand.
Thanks, John

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the quality of lego replicas on Aliexpress?](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/6799/what-is-the-quality-of-lego-replicas-on-aliexpress)

Answer (score 7):

Legoings seems to be the reincarnation of LEPIN, which had some of its factories (or more like sweatshops judging by the published pictures) raided late April this year (2019). Expect quality to be similar, with the usual disregard to workers’ conditions, quality and safety of materials and foremost intellectual property rights of others (TLG and MOC builders in the LEGO community).

I predict it will be shut down in due time as well. I strongly discourage buying their products for the above reasons. Also note that a collection tainted with bootleg bricks will have very little value to a collector, unlike proper LEGO sets.